# How to design a recyclerview with each item containing 2 buttons beside an imageview in andorid

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a recyclerView where each of the items in the list will show an imageView with 2 buttons on the right of the imageview. I have tried but not really getting there. Some help would be really great.

Here is what i want:

[image]

What i tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgVw_contact"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/album_cover_height_details"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVw_contactName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imgVw_contact"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="myColors"
        android:textColor="@color/album_title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/album_title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgVw_contact" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_newok"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgVw_contact"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imgVw_contact"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.931"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imgVw_contact"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgVw_contact"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.409" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the result is:

[image]

I cant find a reason for why the images are getting round.

Also I have tried to use a drawable for button background but no matter what i create either new image asset or vector asset it becomes huge when i use it as background(as you can see in the screenshot).

Comment: Are you comfortable  in moving to RelativeLayout from ConstraintLayout

Comment: i don't mind but i thought constraint layouts are more convenient.

Comment: Then let me help you with RelativeLayout

Comment: that would be great if it helps with my issues which are- imageview is showing round image and my created image/vector assets are getting huge.

Comment: Do you need the textview

Comment: ahh sorry. I forgot to put it in my example image. Would be great if i can get a textview too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. I found out the reasons behind my issues.

issue 1: There is a ic_launcher.xml(anydpi) inside mipmap which is a round cornered one. So when I was setting ic_launcher as background it takes this one .

issue 2: the images used inside the buttons get the full height width of button and becomes huge.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the design you need using ConstrainLayout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgVw_contact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtVw_contactName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="myColors"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imgVw_contact" />

<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_clear_black_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_check_circle_black_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The corresponding layout image is -

[image: Layout]

Comment: is it ok if i use android support library constraintlayout instead of androidx constraintlayout?

Comment: Yes, it's okay though you should switch to AndroidX

Answer (score 0):

I have see your layout . and try to make it . Here is the code

**Try this**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/house1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_highlight_off_black_24dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_vpn_key_black_24dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```